# I am using the AnimatedTextKit plugin, the problem is the text disappears once display

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using the AnimatedTextKit plugin, the problem is the text disappears once display.

Once the text appears on the screen it should keep displaying.
**My code**

```
DefaultTextStyle(
      style: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 25,
        color: Colors.white,
        shadows: [
          Shadow(
            blurRadius: 7.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            offset: Offset(0, 0),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: AnimatedTextKit(
        // pause: Duration(minutes:20),
        totalRepeatCount: 1,
        displayFullTextOnTap: true,
        repeatForever: true,
        isRepeatingAnimation: false,
        animatedTexts: [
          FlickerAnimatedText(
            lable,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ],
        onTap: () {
          print("Tap Event");
        },
      ),
    );
```

**screenshot:**

- It appears as shown in the image

[image]

- it disappeared like that

[image]